# Extracting filename from content disposition via PHP

Tags: php, preg-match, content-disposition

I need a regex to extract the filename (incl. file extension) from the following string:

```
attachment; filename*=UTF-8''test.rar
```

or like this

```
attachment; filename*=UTF-8''Epost%20-test.part01.rar
```

Target:

```
test.rar
Epost%20-test.part01.rar
```

How can I do this?

Note: I'm using preg_match for extracting

Comment: Will the file have every time a `.` dot and nothing else?

Comment: every file has a extension like above (e.g. rar). I don't see what you are asking. I need to extract test.rar

Comment: Then i hope my answer solves your problem :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $str = "attachment; filename*=UTF-8''test.rar";

    preg_match_all("/\w+\.\w+/", $str, $output);

    echo $output[0][0];

?>
```

Output:

```
test.rar
```

**EDIT:**

If the 2 single quotes are every time in the string you can grab every thing after with:

```
<?php

    $str = "attachment; filename*=UTF-8''Epost%20-test.part01.rar";

    preg_match_all("/[^\'\']+$/", $str, $output);

    echo $output[0][0];

?>
```

Output:

```
Epost%20-test.part01.rar
```

Comment: Why down vote? It works and is exactly what op wants?!

Comment: Ahh.... now, I know what you are asking about. Sorry for inconvenience. The file name could also be like this: attachment; filename*=UTF-8''Epost%20-test.part01.rar

Comment: @user2826075 Are the 2 single quotes ever time there?

Comment: This doesn't work if there is a space in the filename.

Answer (score 3):

After several tries I understood (thanks, Julian Reschke) that it's not possible to implement the logic of a header value parsing correctly according to [RFC 2616](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6266) in a simple function. Also it requires a lot of tests to ensure the implementation is correct.

Providing that there is still no solution for that I decided to publish the [dedicated library](https://github.com/cardinalby/phpContentDisposition) with `ContentDisposition` class.

```
composer require cardinalby/content-disposition
```

It can both generate/format a value and parse a string. The example of parsing:

```php
use cardinalby\ContentDisposition\ContentDisposition;

$cd = ContentDisposition::parse('attachment; filename="plans.pdf"');
assert($cd->getType() === 'attachment');
assert($cd->getFilename() === 'plans.pdf');
assert($cd->getParameters() === ['filename' => 'plans.pdf']);
```

```php
use cardinalby\ContentDisposition\ContentDisposition;

$cd = ContentDisposition::parse(
    'attachment; filename="EURO rates.pdf"; filename*=UTF-8\'\'%E2%82%AC%20rates.pdf'
    );
assert($cd->getType() === 'attachment');
// Unicode version is preferable
assert($cd->getFilename() === '€ rates.pdf');
assert($cd->getParameters() === [
    'filename' => 'EURO rates.pdf', 
    'filename*' => '€ rates.pdf'
]);
```

Comment: There is no specified "file" attribute in Content-Disposition.

Comment: @JulianReschke Thx, you are right, it's a mistake in the comment, I have just fixed it. The code snippet is correct, it checks `name` and `filename` attributes.

Comment: "name" isn't specified neither. You really just need "filename":

Comment: @JulianReschke Edited, thanks again, you are right: `name` has a completely different meaning.

Comment: The code above will likely trip over a ";" in quoted string parameter.

Comment: @JulianReschke thanks for comments, I finally returned to complete the gestalt, hope it should work this time

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your Content-Disposition header as string in $contentDisposition, the trick is to use `parse_ini_string`:

```
$parts = explode(';', $contentDisposition);
foreach($parts as $p)
    if(stripos($p, 'filename') !== FALSE) {
        $kv = parse_ini_string($p);
        return $kv['filename'];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any simple solution that works with all the variations mentioned here and on similar questions. Here is my solution to accomplish that.

```
<?php
preg_match('/filename(\*)?=(UTF-8\'\')?"?([^";]+)"?;?/', $_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_DISPOSITION'], $matches);
$file_path = urldecode($matches[3]);
?>
```

That's it, but since we are probably going to write the file to disk, we can add some path sanitization and get the path parts.

```
$regex_array = array(
  '/\.{2,}\//', //prevents changing directory to parent directories
  '/^\/+/' //prevents using root directory or absolute path
);
$path_parts = pathinfo(preg_replace($regex_array, '', $file_path));
echo $path_parts['dirname'];
echo $path_parts['basename'];
echo $path_parts['extension'];
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n";
```

Here are some examples.

Input strings:

1. attachment; filename="newdir/image%20'1.jpg"
2. attachment; filename*=UTF-8''newdir/image%20'2.jpg;
3. attachment; filename*=UTF-8''///../usr/bin....//newdir/image%20'3.jpg;

Output file paths with directory sanitization.

1. newdir/image '1.jpg
2. newdir/image '2.jpg
3. usr/bin/newdir/image '3.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try simply using look behind

```
$str = "attachment; filename*=UTF-8''test.rar";

preg_match('/(?<=\')[a-z-A-Z0-9 -,.()%]*/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

**DEMO** : https://www.regex101.com/r/yO9nQ4/1

Comment: No match with: `attachment; filename*=UTF-8''Epost%20-test.part01.rar` i think you want to edit your answer

Comment: Ok, i will do it...@Rizier123

Answer (score -3):

you need to give some more info. 
is the first part always the same? is the filename always at the end, right after '' ?

--edit--

if you just need to remove the first part then don't use regexp

```
$str = "attachment; filename*=UTF-8''test.rar";

$filename = substr($str, 29);
```

Comment: Uii is there some hidden answer i don't see in this comment?

Comment: the filename is always at the end. I need to remove `attachment; filename*=UTF-8''`

Comment: above is not answer to question you should add this on comment