# PHP Extract binary data from header

Tags: php, email-attachments

I am working on my PHP to extract the binary data that I stored the email header in the mysql database. I need some help with extract the binary data to get the attachment binary data.

Example:

```
UEsDBBQAAAAIAEpZrEjPyoXURw....etc
```

I don't know how do you extract the binary data if you are looking for a filename, example: email_example1.zip.

Here is the header:

```
Return-Path: <sender@domain.com>
Delivered-To: chris@domain.com
Received: from domain.com

------=_Part_4094373_1508330616.1564422111167
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="email_example1.zip"
Content-ID: <05063d19-5033-af14-87e2-d2fbf22d5857@yahoo.com>

UEsDBBQAAAAIAEpZrEjPyoXURw....etc


------=_Part_4094373_1508330616.1564422111167
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="example2.zip"
Content-ID: <3b2c4fee-2b28-778b-b27f-c63881d64e17@domain.com>

UEsDBBQAAAAIALtk6U5W+XzU7iM....etc
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//Connect to the database
include('config.php');

$id = $_GET['id'];
$attid = $_GET['attid'];
$message_id = $_GET['msgid'];
$mailbox_sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $mailfolder . ' WHERE email_id = ? AND message_id = ?';
$mailbox = $link->prepare($mailbox_sql);
$mailbox->execute([$id,$message_id]); 

// set the resulting array to associative
$row = $mailbox->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


if (is_array($row)) {
   $attached = $row['attached_files'];
   $attached_arr = explode("\n", $attached);
}

foreach ($attached_arr as $files) {
    $attached_file = 'attid: ' . $attid . ' filename:';
    $attached = '';

    if (strpos($files,  ' attid: ') !== false) {
        $filename = trim(strrchr($files, ':'), ': ');
        $files = 'attid: ' . $attid . ' filename: ' . $filename;
    }


    if (strpos($files, $attached_file) !== false) {
       $attached = trim(strrchr($files, ':'), ': ');
    }

mailbox = null;
?>
```

Do you know how I can search the filename in the email header to extract the binary data?

Any advice would be much appreicated.

Comment: That is some sort of encoding, perhaps base64?

Comment: @user3783243 yes it is, i want to extract the encoding data. Do you know how??

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

Comment: @bumperbox I know how to use base64_decode but i am talking about how to search for the base64 encode string, e.g: `UEsDBBQAAAAIAEpZrEjPyoXURw....etc`. Do you know how i can get the base64 encode string when i search for the filename??

Comment: The binary data is within the body you have `Content-Type: application/zip` . The file name is exposed via Content-Disposition Header `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="email_example1.zip"` you can just parse the file name. If this doesn't answer your question please explain better what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Ahmed Jaouadi yes I want to parse the filename but like I said I dont know how to parse the binary data `UEsDBBQAAAAIAEpZrEjPyoXURw....etc` when I want to search for the filename like `email_example1.zip`. Do you know how?

Comment: @chrisoojer Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need get the input stream directly from the body because your content is application/zip `Content-Type: application/zip` .

To do that u can use `php://input` :

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
$binary = base64ToBinary($input);

function base64ToBinary(string $string): string {
    if (strpos($string, ';base64,') !== false) {
        $string = explode(';base64,', $string)[1];
    }

    return base64_decode($string);
}
```

The file name is exposed via Content-Disposition Header:
In your post you have `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="email_example1.zip"` you can just parse it from there.

**EDIT**

How to parse your file name from Header:

```
$value = $_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_DISPOSITION'];
$filename = 'default_name.zip';

if (preg_match('/filename="-(.*?)-"/', $value, $match) == 1) {
    $filename = $match[1];
}
```

The code I provided works 100% for the Content Disposition Header you provided:

[image]

If it doesn't work for you that means the format you posted is wrong and check this Question for an answer on [how to get file name from content disposition header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754874/extracting-filename-from-content-disposition-via-php) .

Otherwise your request has nothing to do about Binary data it's parsing about parsing value from string. Please update your question description to match what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you but this is NOT the answer I am looking for. like I said in my previous comment I want to parse the filename to get the base64 code like `UEsDBBQAAAAIAEpZrEjPyoXURw....etc`. Is that clear now??

Comment: The code you post on answer is just convert from base64 to binary. I am looking for how to parse the filename to get the base64 string.

Comment: It should be something like this `$str = 'filename="example2.zip"';
preg_match('/^.*?filename=(["\'])1/m', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);`

Comment: @chrisoojer Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, but it did not pass on if preg_match. Please check again.

Comment: Check my edited answer